# Is there a clean way to build generic type arguments in Autofac?

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I've been trying to inject an array of generic objects into a constructor for a generic type and can't find a clean way to do so.

I have a class like the below:

```
public sealed class RepositoryConsumer<T> : IRepositoryConsumer<T> Where T : BaseEntity
{
   private readonly IOtherDependency _otherDependency;
   private readonly IReadOnlyCollection<IRepository<T>> _regionalRepositories;

   public RepositoryConsumer<T>(
      IOtherDependency otherDependency,
      IReadOnlyCollection<IRepository<T>> regionalRepositories)
   {
      _otherDependency = otherDependency;
      _regionalRepositories = regionalRepositories;
   }
...
```

I need to configure the `IRepository<T>` instances manually, because they will depend on other factors in the application. (e.g. certain regions available which are driven from config, types of `T` which are valid for only specific regions... etc.)

What I currently have to do configure this injection in an Autofac module is below, but it feels like there should be a better way.

```
private void BindRepositoryConsumers(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(IRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>));
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RepositoryConsumer<>))
                .As(typeof(IRepositoryConsumer<>))
                .WithParameter(
                    (parameter, context) => ParameterTypeIsReadonlyCollectionOfIRepositories(parameter),
                    (parameter, context) =>
                    {
                        var type = parameter.ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments.First().GenericTypeArguments.First();
                        return GetType()
                            .GetMethod(nameof(CreateRepositories))
                            .MakeGenericMethod(type)
                            .Invoke(this, BindingFlags.Default, null, new object[] { context }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    }).SingleInstance();
        }

        private static bool ParameterTypeIsReadonlyCollectionOfRepositories(ParameterInfo parameter)
        {
            return parameter.ParameterType.IsGenericType &&
                   parameter.ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().First().IsGenericType &&
                   typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<>)
                       .MakeGenericType(typeof(IRepository<>).MakeGenericType(parameter.ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments.First().GenericTypeArguments.First()))
                       .IsAssignableFrom(parameter.ParameterType);
        }

        public static IReadOnlyCollection<IRepository<T>> CreateRepositories<T>(IComponentContext context) where T : BaseEntity
        {
            var repositoryProvider = context.Resolve<IRepositoryProvider>();
            var config = context.Resolve<IConfig>();

            var regionalRepositories = config.Regions.Select(region => repositoryProvider.Create<T>(region));

            return regionalRepositories;
        }
```

Does anyone have a better/cleaner way of implementing this? I don't like dynamically invoking a method in there.

Comment: Where do you use `T` in `CreateRepositories` ? did you mean `context.Resolve<IRepositoryProvider<T>>` ?

Comment: It'll be in `RepositoryProvider.Create()`. I'll amend the sample.

Comment: You should be able to create your own `IRegistrationSource` to provide the `IReadOnlyCollection<IRepository<T>>`. This way you won't have to use the `WithParameter` method, Autofac will use the custom registration source when it need to resolve a `IReadOnlyCollection<IRepository<T>>`

Comment: Sory even with a custom registration source you will have to call the `Create<T>` from a non generic context. To easily mix them generic and non generic context you can introduce a non generic `IRepositoryProvider` interface and a generic one `IRepositoryProvider<T>`